# Multispeaker option with BASS library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, speaker, bass

I'm working on a sonification project where I have to track a colored object from my camera and play music if that object moves in different positions, e.g.: play music on the right speaker if the object moves right.

I've been looking for an audio library on internet, but haven't found a solution. I tried to use the BASS audio library, but I couldn't find any tutorials for it. I need to use BASS because I read that it has a multispeaker Option.

Does anyone know how to use this multispeaker option?

Comment: Have you looked at DirectX Audio?

Comment: You can try http://www.fmod.org/, they have a good tutorial to get you started with some code.

Comment: Thank you @Caesar, i will try to stick with BASS libraries but if I see that I cannot manage the multispeaker option i'll try to use fmod...

Comment: @Angel I have used bass library but I'm not an export. What exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: I tried to use the BASSmixer library that lets you choose in what speaker you want to play sound. But since i couldn't find an helpful guide, i wasn't able to do it... tried to use Bass_mixer_StreadAddChannel but kept on having problems and errors :( 
Do you know a function that lets you choose the speaker?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. I personally recommend you to use [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) or [fmod](http://www.fmod.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.. I tried DirectSound, but it didn't work. OpenAl it's not good for what i'm trying to do, i read that it doesn't have a multispeaker option... does it?? 

Is there anyone that uses BASS libraries that can help me?

Comment: in openal you set the positions of the listener and the sound source, and the library figures out which speaker it should play on...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you start by looking at the examples provided with the library. When you get to something that you don't understand, try going to the documentation page and searching for functions: http://www.un4seen.com/doc/.

If all else fails, try looking around on the BASS forum.

Comment: I already tried to look at that documentation but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @Angel That documentation by itself isn't going to teach you much. You need to look at the examples that came with the BASS library. You can use the documentation as a reference, i.e. figure out what the example code is doing.

Comment: As I already said it wasn't helpful. That's the reason why i posted the question....I'm sorry if i might have explained myself wrong, i'm not a native emglish speaker. I decided to write this question because i didn't find helpful any of the examples  that came with the BASS library.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using IrrKlang. With this library I can manage the 3D sound tracking project... I recommend to use this library, it's the most accurate and helpful that I found.